# Why is the index of the last row of my excel table out of range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to dynamically reference the last row of the following table:

[image]

I'm using the following formula to determine what the last row is: `=ROW(OFFSET(A2,COUNTA(Table2[Survey ID])-1,0))`

In this case this returns 25 into the cell M30

The I'm trying to use this formula to Index the last row of the table which is row 25 and index the force in the last row of the table `=INDEX(Table2[Force], $M$30)`

In this case it should return Newcastle but all I get is #Ref!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first formula is obtaining the row the last entry is in. You are then using that value as the index value for your lookup.

Unfortunately, you have a mismatch:  the row value you obtain is one greater than the number of data rows in the table since there is a header row above the data rows. So you obtain 25, which is the row the last data is in. All good, except that you then use `INDEX()` on the data rows, not the data rows PLUS header row. So you look for the 25th row of data when only 24 exist. Ergo the error.

Just subtract one from the first formula's result. Either:

```
=ROW(OFFSET(A2,COUNTA(Table2[Survey ID])-1,0)) - 1
```

or

```
=INDEX(Table2[Force], $M$30 - 1)
```

will work, though the first is "cleaner" as it makes the first a completed result, therefore contained wholly in the single cell, rather than a partial result that needs massaged later. (Either conceptual approach works, but this is better for the scenario. If you had several uses for the value 25 and only one or a couple needed to reduce it to 24 while others needed the raw 25, then the second approach would probably be better. Or not, depending on what those uses did. Anyway...)

In the vein of "Or you can do it THIS way instead, then talk about which way is better, like I did just last paragraph"... you can change the lookup formula a different way so that the Table reference includes the header row and your 25 is then fine:

```
=INDEX(Table2[[#All],[Force]], $M$30)
```

Gosh, just love how using Tables makes everything soooo easy... No problems ever again. Surf the hype... MS and help site babble of the last 15 years aside, Table referencing is every bit as nuanced and complicated as direct cell referencing and the only real value is MS chose to fix making ranges dynamic via Tables rather than having a simple solution avaiable via simple ranges. So when using Tables, pay very close attention to the references you generate as not every formula failure leads to an obvious error like here. Some simply have plausible but very wrong values returned and can persist for years.

Answer (score 0):

**Table name: tbl**   --> K1:K7

| n | Column K | Column M |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Arrx | M |
| 2 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 |  |
| 4 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 2 |  |
| 6 | 8 |  |
| 7 | 20 |  |

| Excel 365: | result | CELL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =take(row(tbl[Arrx]),-1) | 7 |  |
| =take(tbl[Arrx],-1) | 20 |  |
| **other versions** |  |  |
| =row(offset(K2,COUNT(tbl[Arrx])-1,0)) | 7 | M2 |
| =INDEX(tbl[Arrx], $M$2- 1) | 20 |  |

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).